# Plugin access to average users not only admin

Tags: plugin-development

I'm new to plugin writing, but intermediate in theme making. I wonder if it is possible to write a plugin, to add addition functionality for users, who don't have admin status. Can I give them permission for upload images and so on? Can I write a plugin, what help no admin users upload and manage their images, and some personal texts?

Answer (score 1):

The rules for themes and plugins are basically the same.  You can make plugins and themes administrable by anyone in most respects except that non-admins can't install and uninstall plugins/themes.

For instance, you should use the if_current_user_can('do_stuff') conditional to handle permissions on operations.  Also, the add_menu_page() function lets you specify what capabilities a user needs to have to be able to see it.  Same as a theme.

Make sense?